# FilesMatch in htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Suddenly my WordPress site is not working - looking at `.htaccess` it has

```
<FilesMatch ".(py|exe|php)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^(about.php|radio.php|index.php|content.php|lock360.php|admin.php|wp-login.php|wp-l0gin.php|wp-theme.php|wp-scripts.php|wp-editor.php|mah.php|jp.php|ext.php)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

From where did `<FilesMatch ".(py|exe|php)$">` come in all of a sudden ?

Comment: If your `.htaccess` file changed without your intervention, you should contact your hosting provider's support team ASAP.

Comment: Is it possible for the .htaccess to be changed remotely via a plugin that has a vulnerability ?

Comment: If the vulnerability allows the plugin to write to the filesystem, then yes, it's possible. Talk to your hosting provider's support team.

Answer (score 0):

I think  that WordPress rules should be wrapped in

```
# BEGIN WordPress

Rewrite rules...

# END WordPress
```

so maybe you got hacked ?